# Socket.io / Node.js: "value is out of bounds" on socket connection from client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arm, base64, engine.io

I am working on getting nodejs / socket.io / express running on busybox linux on an ARMv5TE processor. I have nodejs up and running and the following code runs without errors.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Until I try to connect via websocket from a client. From the browser (with the client script `socket.io.js` loaded), `var socket = io.connect('ws://192.168.1.8:3000');` or `var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.8:3000');`. Node then logs this error to the console and stops:

```
buffer.js:784
    throw TypeError('value is out of bounds');

TypeError: value is out of bounds
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at checkInt (buffer.js:784:11)
    at Buffer.writeInt32BE (buffer.js:924:5)
    at Base64Id.generateId (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/base64id/lib/base64id.js:88:8)
    at Server.handshake (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:222:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:184:12
    at Server.checkRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:67:51)
    at Server.verify (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:127:17)
    at Server.handleRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:174:8)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:362:12)
```

Running the same node server from my desktop computer (Windows 8 64 bit), does not produce this error.

I can trace the error to these lines of code in `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/base64id/lib/base64id.js`:

```
Base64Id.prototype.generateId = function () {
    var rand = new Buffer(15); // multiple of 3 for base64
    if (!rand.writeInt32BE) {
        return Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString() + Math.abs(Math.random() * Math.random() * Date.now() | 0).toString();
    }
this.sequenceNumber = (this.sequenceNumber + 1) | 0;
rand.writeInt32BE(this.sequenceNumber, 11);
...
```

If I change `rand.writeInt32BE(this.sequenceNumber, 11);` to `rand.writeInt32BE(this.sequenceNumber, 11, true);`, the error goes away and I can continue  on without problems (presumably). So:

- Why does this error occur when running my code from the ARMv5TE machine?
- Is my change to `base64id.js` safe or appropriate?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that object in a JSON.stringify so you have JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' }) ?

Comment: I still get the same error. That code is lifted straight from the socket.io examples: http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: I copy pasted and it worked for me? the ports and ip had to be changed of course, but really that was it.

Comment: Did you run it with node on an ARMv5TE processor? This same code works fine for me when I run it with node on my Windows machine too. I think this is a problem with node on ARMv5TE specifically.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, it sounds like the socket.io native stuff is causing problems, in particular it could be the things in the ws dependency. Maybe try doing a basic example with the ws module to verify? there could also be some magic flag for node-gyp you could add in to change how things are compiled. I think it boils down to the platform specific size of certain types in the C++ code, but then again it could be much less complicated than that.